# Controle de versão de dependências

Tags: python, django

Uso `python`, `Django` em um servidor com `CloudFoundry` instalado. Lá, consigo manter o meu `requirements.txt` com todas as dependências da minha aplicação e, por segurança, mantenho sempre o nome exato da versão de cada plugin pra evitar crashes inesperados por incompatibilidade com novas versões.

```
Werkzeug==1.0.0.2
Django==1.11
```

Quais as melhores práticas pra se acompanhar as versões das minhas dependências em uma aplicação "séria" (grande porte)? Inscrevo-me nas listas de distribuição de e-mail de cada plugin pra receber informações de atualizações mas nem sempre elas existem.

Imagino que essa pergunta seja aplicável a outros ambientes/frameworks.

Comment: Se ao invés de eu perguntar quais são as melhores, eu perguntasse quais opções disponíveis, reabriria? Ou ainda é muito ampla?

Answer (score 2):

Eu vi alguns projetos usando badges de serviços externos como o https://requires.io/

Eles tem plano grátis para projetos open source e planos pagos.

Você também pode rodar `pip list -o` que vai listar os pacotes que tem atualização disponível, você pode colocar esse comando rodando uma vez por dia no seu CI e ter um alerta se o comando tiver algum output.

Comment: O requires.io me pareceu muito interessante pra quem usa GitHub. Vou deixar a pergunta em aberto, por enquanto, pra ver se vejo algum exemplo de grandes aplicações em produção.